# debug wordpress ram and connections usage in AWS

Tags: wordpress, debugging, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have problem with one WordPress hosted on AWS website many time it's stop 
after many check I find the errors in AWS log

```
[Tue Dec 22 14:09:46.563428 2015] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 1121] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
```

it's related that Apache has many connections and reach his limits 
or that the site use too much ram .

I try many plugins but couldn't get for sure where is the parts that use so much ram in my site or why the connections not close

the points I really need help with
1- know the how my website use the ram ...
2- know the connections (more info about each one)

Comment: Are you using apache with php-fpm and mod_fcgi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve this I did the following

1. configure Apache and MySQL ram usage and connections .
2. create a Swap big ( 2G )
3. increase the wordpress memory .

in wordpress

1. use plugins to see the impact of the plugins on the site .
2. refactor and replace non famous or well tested plugins .